# How to initialize this.props into this.state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-apollo

There are multiple input values in a prop, but the value I require is in state. I am said not to initialize this.props=this.state as props is read-only.

I had tried this.props=this.state and it did work.

```
const prevHouse = this.props.house; // This has multiple input values

prevHouse.rent = this.state.rent; //State is given input value
```

Is the above use of syntax is correct and what is the solution for this ?

Update : changing this.props.house to prevHouse in above

Comment: No, this syntax is incorrect and you can't initialize props in the child component you can initialize or change its values only in the parent component.

Comment: Okay, what is the alternative b'cos this.props.sale is coming from GraphQL database.

Comment: so, you want to change this.props.sale's value or want to save in state what exactly your problem and share your code so that we can help you.

Comment: I want to change this.props.sale's value

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Here is my code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56746125/how-to-use-this-state-rent-value-instead-of-this-props-house-rent-value-in-cache please go through

Answer (score 1):

You can make a copy of the props and put it into the state. If your goal is to change state in the parent's component state from the child. You need to use Context Api or Redux

Comment: So my above syntax is correct ? because I kept a copy of props into state

Answer (score 0):

You could pass your prop value into state when the component mounts. You could do this as follows using the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method:

```
componentDidMount() {

    this.setState({
      rent: this.props.house.rent
    })

  }
```

This way, when the component mounts your state value `rent` will be the value of `this.props.house.rent`. You could then do this for each of the props you need in state.

Some more info on ComponentDidMount can be found at the [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Comment: You'd probably want to do this in `componentDidUpdate` so it will set state every time the prop changes. Unless the OP does not want that as a desired side effect of course :)

Comment: Setting state in `componentDidUpdate ` can create an infinite loop and cause a crash. Need to be defensive if this is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize state the same with props like this using spread operator

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        ...props //this mean the value of state will filled with all of the object values in props object without need assigning one by one object values
    }

}
```